# How do I disable soft delete of an Azure API Management instance when deploying using an ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, soft-delete

In my project team we have an Azure DevOps pipeline that tears down a particular resource group in our CI environment, and then the next day it redeploys it using an ARM template.

In ~Spring 2021 it seems the soft delete option was auto-enabled on Azure API Management instances, and so now this pipeline is failing.  This is because you can't deploy a resource of the same name as one that has been soft deleted, and these aren't automatically purged until 48 hours after deletion.  As the pipeline tries to redeploy the API Management instance within this timeframe, it fails.  The time between tear down and redeployment cannot be extended.

There's this documentation for [API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/soft-delete), but that's for REST API calls, and I want to know if it can be specified in the ARM template deployment.

There's also this documentation for a [keyvault resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults?tabs=json#code-try-0:%7E:text=%22enableSoftDelete%22%3A%20%22boolean%22%2C), perhaps I can use something similar?  I'm not sure where I'd put it, however.

Any relevant advice welcome.  TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/257072/azure-api-management-already-exists.html and see if this helps. You may want to raise a [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management) on UserVoice to support.

You may try to create a script to check “List deleted services by subscription” REST API to check if the deleted APIM services are in "soft deleted" state, it will also returned the date when the API Management service is going to be purged.
[Deleted Services - List By Subscription (Azure API Management) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2021-01-01-preview/deleted-services/list-by-subscription)

Comment: This was the approach we went for in the end.  Adding in a script to purge soft deleted APIM instances.

Answer (score 1):

Currently only option is to purge (not available via ARM template) and then deploy.  We are considering options to alleviate such concerns.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can delete an API Management service explicitly and specify the 2019-12-01 API version to use (not sure what you use to delete RGs, but e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/remove-azresource?view=azps-5.7.0). That way the service will be hard-deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing, where I needed to wait x hours before being able to recreate the resource with the same name.
By using the APIM management api, you can force Azure to immediately delete the resource.
Check this operation to purge the resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/soft-delete#purge-a-soft-deleted-apim-instance

The docs allow you to directly perform the operation on your Azure subscription. Alternatively you can use this to list all soft-deleted instances for a given subscription:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/deletedservices?api-version=2020-06-01-preview
```

And this one to purge a soft-deleted APIM instance:

```
DELETE https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/locations/{location}/deletedservices/{serviceName}?api-version=2020-06-01-preview
```

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your Answer is self contained, meaning the answer needs to be here in the Answer itself. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be preferable if you could answer the Question in your own words here and link only as a reference. What is "this operation"? How does it work?